# how to align sign up navbar button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have good knowledge of HTML, however im still learning css. Im trying to get my sign up button to be at the far right, without it being a part of the main navigation link div. Does anyone know how i would make my sign up button appear at the far right? (As of right now my sign up button appears under the Company drop down, and im trying to get it to appear at the very far right.

I have tried using the translate property, to translate the buttons over to the left to fit my sign up button, however it also makes the mobile version of the navbar inaccessible.

My navbar links are already aligned. its just my sign up button, which is not in the same div as the navbar links. I have posted snippets of my css and html. (i also use bootstrap)

Here is a snippet of my code:

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
              <img src="assets/images/logo-l.png" class="img-fluid" alt="img" /> CherryBerry <span class="text-red"> Studios </span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="knowledge-base.php">Knowledge Base</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                      Company
                    </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/about.php">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Mission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Partners</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Affiliates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Legal Info</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="support.php">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="support.php">Our Team</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="signup.php" class="btn btn-menu">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');



body {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #0d0d0d;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #00FF00; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
}

.f15 {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}

.f400 {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.f500 {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.f600 {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.f700 {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.bg-dark {
    background: #111 !important;
}

.bg-light {
    background: #efefef8c !important;
}

select:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

input:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.gray {
    color: #d0cece;
}

.icon-item {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.about-text {
    font-size: 19px;
}

/*navbar begin.*/

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
    background: #111;
}

    .navbar .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #808080;
        transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
    }

     .navbar .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        color: #ff00ff;
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown-menu a:focused {
        color: #ff00ff;
        background-color: #111;
    }

.navbar .dropdown-divider {
    border-top: 1px solid #252424;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #808080;
    transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item.active, .navbar .dropdown-item:active {
    background: #111;
}

.btn-menu {
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 6px 20px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 33px;
    transition: background-color ease-in 0.25s, color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.footer-link {
    transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    color: #ff00ff !important;
}

.btn-menu:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.btn1 {
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: background-color ease-in 0.25s, color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.btn1:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
    color: #000000; 
}

.btn2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
}

header {
    background: black;
}

.home-banner .owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    font-size: 54px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    left: 46px;
}

.home-banner .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 46px;
    top: 40%;
    font-size: 54px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.home-banner .owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: 0 0;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #eeeeee !important;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

    .home-banner .owl-carousel button.owl-dot.active {
        background: #d1a236 !important;
    }

.home-banner .owl-dots {
    position: relative;
    top: -53px;
    margin-bottom: -36px;
}

.cover {
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
}

.cover-shade {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
    padding: 200px 0px;
}

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
    }

    .cover-shade p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

.details-box {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #1f1f1f 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.text-red {
    color: #d34037;
}

.text-grey {
    color: #888;
}

.l-head {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.line {
    width: 140px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #d34037;
}

.line-s {
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #d34037;
}

.head2 {
    font-size: 49px;
}

.head3 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.form-label-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.bg-color {
    background: #000;
}

.services-item {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #181818 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    border: 1px solid #27313f;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 30px 25px 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .services-item::before, .services-item::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -60px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 320px;
        background: #d34037;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        opacity: 0.55;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .services-item::after {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
        transform: rotate(55deg);
    }

.services-sub {
    margin: 0 0 33px;
}

    .services-sub::before, .services-sub::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 75px;
        top: -50px;
        width: 1px;
        height: 260px;
        background: green;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .services-sub::after {
        left: auto;
        right: 75px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
        transform: rotate(55deg);
    }

    .services-sub img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -o-border-radius: 50%;
        -ms-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21), inset 0px 3px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
        max-width: 200px;
    }
/*footer begin.*/
footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}

.list1 a {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    .list1 a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

footer p {
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

footer h5 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.social-list2 a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #111;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px !important;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .social-list2 a:hover {
        background: #fff;
    }

.copyrights {
    background: #090909;
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

    .copyrights p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

.faqs-container-cs p {
    color: white;
}

.faqs-container-cs .accordion-body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #1f1f1f 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    background: #111;
}


.faqs-container-cs .accordion-button {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: #000;
}

    .faqs-container-cs .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
        background-color: #000 !important;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .faqs-container-cs .accordion-button::after {
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='white'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    }

.link-text {
    color: #eeeeee !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/**/

.reg-form {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #000;
}

    .reg-form .form-control {
        border: 1px solid #a5a7a8 !important;
    }

    .reg-form .form-select {
        border: 1px solid #a5a7a8 !important;
    }


.btn-facebook {
    background-color: #405d9d;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-google {
    background-color: #c5665f;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-facebook:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #405d9d;
}

.btn-google:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #c5665f;
}

.bg-grd {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #5a8cc638);
}

.divider-text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

    .divider-text span {
        padding: 7px;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: #222;
    }

    .divider-text:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        top: 55%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

.label-fr {
    color: #b9b5b5;
}

.background-div {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.text-links:hover {
    color: lime;
}

.text-links:active {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.input-group-custom {
    height: 48px;
    color: #b9b5b5;
}

.input-group-custom-field {
    color: #ff0000;
    background: none;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 42px;
}

.checkbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}        

input[type=checkbox] {
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    transform: translateY(4px)
}

input[type=checkbox]::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
    transform: translate(8px, 13px) rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 150ms all linear;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

input[type=checkbox]::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
    transform: translate(1px, 8px) rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 150ms all linear;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

        input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
    width: 14px;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

        input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
    width: 10px;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/*@media(min-width:992px) {


    .mobile-nav {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media(max-width:992px) {
    .desktop-nav {
        display: none !important;
    }
}*/

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .navbar-nav a {
        padding-left: 10px !important;
        padding-right: 10px !important;
    }
}


@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .head2 {
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
}


@media(max-width:767px) {

    .navbar .container-fluid{
        padding:0px !important
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        font-size:18px !important
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
    width: 25px;
    }
    .cover-shade {
        padding: 100px 0px;
    }

    .home-banner .owl-prev {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .home-banner .owl-next {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .head3 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .l-head {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .head2 {
        font-size: 38px;
    }

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 43px;
    }

    .cover-shade p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
/* Disclaimer popup*/
.dis-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px; 
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    height: 140px;
}

.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
}

.dis-btn {
  max-height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-25px)
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dis-popup {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .dis-popup p {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .dis-popup {
      height: 125px
    }

    .dis-btn {
      margin-top: 15px;
      transform: translateY(-37px)
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .dis-btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

/* Loading Screen */
.loading-screen {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000; /* Set a black background */
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column; /* Center the content vertically */
}

.loading-spinner-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column; /* Center the content horizontally and stack them vertically */
}

.loading-spinner {
    width: 150px; /* Make the spinner 3x larger */
    height: 150px; /* Make the spinner 3x larger */
    position: relative;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #ff0000; /* Set the initial color for the spinner border (red) and make it about 3/4 of a full circle */
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite, color-change 4s linear infinite; /* Apply spinning and color-change animations to the spinner */
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6); /* Add a red box shadow to the spinner */
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0%, 100% { border-top-color: #ff0000; } /* Red */
    50% { border-top-color: #00ff00; } /* Green */
}

.loading-spinner-container img {
    max-width: 150px; /* Set the max width for your logo */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between logo and spinner */
}

.loading-screen h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff; /* Set the color for the text (white) */
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add spacing between the spinner and the text */
}

.ld-img {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Newsletter subscription form*/
.nl-form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nl-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nl-form p {
  text-align: center;
  color: lime;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nl-form form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nl-form input[type="email"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
/*newsletter subscription form end.*/

.cbs-form:active {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Error Pages */
.error-page {

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #111, #010101);

    height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {

    from {

        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.animate-flicker {

    animation: fadeIn 1s infinite alternate;

}

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Bootstrap, so please set appropriate question _tags_.

Comment: May not be related to your issue but you have un-closed tags which therefore make your `HTML` code incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `style="float:right;"` as inline style in the submit button like-

> ```
>  <a href="signup.php" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-menu">Sign Up</a>
> ```

Run the snippet to see it in action.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');



body {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #0d0d0d;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #00FF00; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
}

.f15 {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}

.f400 {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.f500 {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.f600 {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.f700 {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.bg-dark {
    background: #111 !important;
}

.bg-light {
    background: #efefef8c !important;
}

select:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

input:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.gray {
    color: #d0cece;
}

.icon-item {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.about-text {
    font-size: 19px;
}

/*navbar begin.*/

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
    background: #111;
}

    .navbar .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #808080;
        transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
    }

     .navbar .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        color: #ff00ff;
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown-menu a:focused {
        color: #ff00ff;
        background-color: #111;
    }

.navbar .dropdown-divider {
    border-top: 1px solid #252424;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #808080;
    transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item.active, .navbar .dropdown-item:active {
    background: #111;
}

.btn-menu {
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 6px 20px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 33px;
    transition: background-color ease-in 0.25s, color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.footer-link {
    transition: color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    color: #ff00ff !important;
}

.btn-menu:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.btn1 {
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: background-color ease-in 0.25s, color ease-in 0.25s;
}

.btn1:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
    color: #000000; 
}

.btn2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
}

header {
    background: black;
}

.home-banner .owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    font-size: 54px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    left: 46px;
}

.home-banner .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 46px;
    top: 40%;
    font-size: 54px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.home-banner .owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: 0 0;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #eeeeee !important;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

    .home-banner .owl-carousel button.owl-dot.active {
        background: #d1a236 !important;
    }

.home-banner .owl-dots {
    position: relative;
    top: -53px;
    margin-bottom: -36px;
}

.cover {
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
}

.cover-shade {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
    padding: 200px 0px;
}

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
    }

    .cover-shade p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

.details-box {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #1f1f1f 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.text-red {
    color: #d34037;
}

.text-grey {
    color: #888;
}

.l-head {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.line {
    width: 140px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #d34037;
}

.line-s {
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #d34037;
}

.head2 {
    font-size: 49px;
}

.head3 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.form-label-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.bg-color {
    background: #000;
}

.services-item {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #181818 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    border: 1px solid #27313f;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 30px 25px 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .services-item::before, .services-item::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -60px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 320px;
        background: #d34037;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        opacity: 0.55;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .services-item::after {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
        transform: rotate(55deg);
    }

.services-sub {
    margin: 0 0 33px;
}

    .services-sub::before, .services-sub::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 75px;
        top: -50px;
        width: 1px;
        height: 260px;
        background: green;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-55deg);
        transform: rotate(-55deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .services-sub::after {
        left: auto;
        right: 75px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
        transform: rotate(55deg);
    }

    .services-sub img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -o-border-radius: 50%;
        -ms-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21), inset 0px 3px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
        max-width: 200px;
    }
/*footer begin.*/
footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}

.list1 a {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    .list1 a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

footer p {
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

footer h5 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.social-list2 a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #111;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px !important;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .social-list2 a:hover {
        background: #fff;
    }

.copyrights {
    background: #090909;
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

    .copyrights p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

.faqs-container-cs p {
    color: white;
}

.faqs-container-cs .accordion-body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #1f1f1f 0%, rgb(0 0 0) 100%);
    background: #111;
}


.faqs-container-cs .accordion-button {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: #000;
}

    .faqs-container-cs .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
        background-color: #000 !important;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .faqs-container-cs .accordion-button::after {
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='white'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    }

.link-text {
    color: #eeeeee !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/**/

.reg-form {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #000;
}

    .reg-form .form-control {
        border: 1px solid #a5a7a8 !important;
    }

    .reg-form .form-select {
        border: 1px solid #a5a7a8 !important;
    }


.btn-facebook {
    background-color: #405d9d;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-google {
    background-color: #c5665f;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-facebook:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #405d9d;
}

.btn-google:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #c5665f;
}

.bg-grd {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #5a8cc638);
}

.divider-text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

    .divider-text span {
        padding: 7px;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: #222;
    }

    .divider-text:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        top: 55%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

.label-fr {
    color: #b9b5b5;
}

.background-div {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.text-links:hover {
    color: lime;
}

.text-links:active {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.input-group-custom {
    height: 48px;
    color: #b9b5b5;
}

.input-group-custom-field {
    color: #ff0000;
    background: none;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 42px;
}

.checkbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}        

input[type=checkbox] {
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    transform: translateY(4px)
}

input[type=checkbox]::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
    transform: translate(8px, 13px) rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 150ms all linear;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

input[type=checkbox]::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
    transform: translate(1px, 8px) rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 150ms all linear;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

        input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
    width: 14px;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

        input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
    width: 10px;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/*@media(min-width:992px) {


    .mobile-nav {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media(max-width:992px) {
    .desktop-nav {
        display: none !important;
    }
}*/

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .navbar-nav a {
        padding-left: 10px !important;
        padding-right: 10px !important;
    }
}


@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .head2 {
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
}


@media(max-width:767px) {

    .navbar .container-fluid{
        padding:0px !important
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        font-size:18px !important
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
    width: 25px;
    }
    .cover-shade {
        padding: 100px 0px;
    }

    .home-banner .owl-prev {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .home-banner .owl-next {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .head3 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .l-head {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .head2 {
        font-size: 38px;
    }

    .cover-shade h1 {
        font-size: 43px;
    }

    .cover-shade p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
/* Disclaimer popup*/
.dis-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px; 
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    height: 140px;
}

.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
}

.dis-btn {
  max-height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-25px)
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dis-popup {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .dis-popup p {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .dis-popup {
      height: 125px
    }

    .dis-btn {
      margin-top: 15px;
      transform: translateY(-37px)
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .dis-btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

/* Loading Screen */
.loading-screen {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000; /* Set a black background */
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column; /* Center the content vertically */
}

.loading-spinner-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column; /* Center the content horizontally and stack them vertically */
}

.loading-spinner {
    width: 150px; /* Make the spinner 3x larger */
    height: 150px; /* Make the spinner 3x larger */
    position: relative;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #ff0000; /* Set the initial color for the spinner border (red) and make it about 3/4 of a full circle */
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite, color-change 4s linear infinite; /* Apply spinning and color-change animations to the spinner */
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6); /* Add a red box shadow to the spinner */
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0%, 100% { border-top-color: #ff0000; } /* Red */
    50% { border-top-color: #00ff00; } /* Green */
}

.loading-spinner-container img {
    max-width: 150px; /* Set the max width for your logo */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between logo and spinner */
}

.loading-screen h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff; /* Set the color for the text (white) */
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add spacing between the spinner and the text */
}

.ld-img {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Newsletter subscription form*/
.nl-form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nl-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nl-form p {
  text-align: center;
  color: lime;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nl-form form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nl-form input[type="email"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
/*newsletter subscription form end.*/

.cbs-form:active {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Error Pages */
.error-page {

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #111, #010101);

    height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {

    from {

        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.animate-flicker {

    animation: fadeIn 1s infinite alternate;

}

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
              <img src="assets/images/logo-l.png" class="img-fluid" alt="img" /> CherryBerry <span class="text-red"> Studios </span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="knowledge-base.php">Knowledge Base</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                      Company
                    </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/about.php">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Mission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Partners</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Affiliates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="story/mission.php">Legal Info</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="support.php">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="support.php">Our Team</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="signup.php" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-menu">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```